# PHP and Function Errors

Tags: php, function, error-handling

I was looking to see what would be the best way to handle errors from functions. Is the "DIE" method appropriate?

ie. php function calls another, for example:

```
function login(){
     $result = verifyDetails("bob", "password123");
     if($result == "accepted"){
          echo "Welcome bob";
     }else{
          echo "Error!! \n";
          echo $result;
     }
}

function verifyDetails($user, $pass){
     if(empty($user) || empty($pass)){
          die("cannot be empty");
     }

     if($user == "bob" && $pass == "password"){
          return "accepted";
     }else{
          die("username or password incorrect");
     }
}
```

does the "DIE" method return the message or does everything come to a standstill?

thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE**

what if the output is not known?

for example. in the above example I have placed "accepted" as the only correct answer.

What if the return is a name or id number.. then you cant really separate the error and correct returns.

thanks again.

---

**UPDATE / Possible Solution**

```
function login(){
     $result = verifyDetails("bob", "password123");
     if($result[0] == "SUCCESS"){
          echo "Welcome bob";
     }else if($result[0] == "ERROR"){
          echo "Error!! \n";
          echo $result;
     }else{
          echo "Unknown Error!!";
     }

}

function verifyDetails($user, $pass){
     $msg = array();

     if(empty($user) || empty($pass)){
          $msg[0] = "ERROR";
          $msg[1] = "cannot be empty"
          return $msg;
     }

     if($user == "bob" && $pass == "password"){
          //say $customerID is extracted from a db
          $msg[0] = "SUCCESS";
          $msg[1] = $customerID
          return $msg;
     }else{
          $msg[0] = "ERROR";
          $msg[1] = "username or password incorrect"
          return $msg;
     }
}
```

ideas & suggestions on the above "possible" solution are welcome

---

**UPDATE**

Check Shikiryu update 2 answer below for a cleaner version using arrays

Comment: You may want to read about Exceptions. Using die() is a relatively good solution when you must terminate the script execution.

Comment: @mailo exceptions shouldn't be used to handle application logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`die()` just `echo` your message and stop the script because [die()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) is an alias of [exit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).

In your case, since the password isn't `password` but `password123`, the script will stop just displaying "username or password incorrect".

But as I can see here, you want a `return "cannot be empty";`, so that it'll display :

> Error!! 
>   username or password incorrect

(and optionally the rest of the html which `die()` won't)

---

Update 2 (ugly way) :

```
function login(){
     $result = verifyDetails("bob", "password123");
     if(isset($result['success']){ // verifyDetails return true?
          echo $result['success'];
     }else{
          echo "Error!! \n";
          echo $result['error']; // Display the error verifyDetails throws
          // You may want to check if $result['error'] exists.
     }
}

function verifyDetails($user, $pass){
     if(empty($user) || empty($pass)){
          return array('error'=>"cannot be empty");
     }

     if($user == "bob" && $pass == "password"){
          return array('success'=>"Welcome bob");
     }else{
          return array('error'=>"username or password incorrect");
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks... the only problem I have if the "return true" is any unknown value... like a customerID or first name" hard to pick what is an error message and what isnt

Comment: @Stevanicus : I updated but I'm not quite satisfied. It works, but looks ugly to me.

Comment: yea that what I put as my possible solution... yours looks cleaner than mine atleast :D but same idea. Like you im not quite satisfied either.

Answer (score 1):

Well the only acceptable way in your case is `return FALSE`

if these functions are really methods of some class, use class variable to store actual errors.
if these functions belongs to no class, I wouldn't use them at all, but write it in plain code

```
 if($user == "bob" && $pass = "password"){
      echo "Welcome bob";
 }else{
       echo "incorrect username or password");
 }
```

**updated answer**

Well there is nothing to invent. Just follow the way PHP goes:
Make your function return either value or FALSE

however, for the validation purpose you have to make it this way:

```
function validSomething($val){
  return (bool)rand(0,1);
}
$err = array();
if (!validSomething($var)) {
  $err[] = "Whatever error";
}
```

i.e. function returns only boolean values and actual error message being added by application logic.

However, in your example user-defined functions are totally misused.

Comment: the problem with just returning false is that, you wont know where the error is

Comment: @Stevanicus see updated answer. make your validation functions check one parameter at a time - so, you will always know. However, talking of such imaginary example a pain. I'd prefer real case to discuss.

Comment: `$pass = "password"` should be `$pass == "password"` here, typo ;) ?

Comment: Ouch typo by the OP, my bad :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel thanks for that... gave me an idea.. I could always return an array.. with the first "slot" being "success" or "error" for example.

Comment: @Stevanicus that's ugly approach I'd say. But I have to admit, no knowledge can came unless through own pain. Good luck :)

Comment: @Stevanicus at least I can say that my code is ten times shorter.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, what if your validSomething, returns a string not a boolean tho.

Comment: @Stevanicus PHP's is_int() doesn't. why validSomething should? anyway, it all depends on situation. That's why I dislike to discuss imaginary code taken out of nowhere. EVery situation has it's solution. And I can say from my 10+ years experience I know most of them (with proper solutions). While your question is too general and can have thousands answers.

Answer (score 1):

`die` terminates the execution of the PHP script at the line it is called. Therefore, your message would no be returned.

You might want to simply use `return` instead of `die`;

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use `die()` to debug.

`does the "DIE" method return the message or does everything come to a standstill?`

Yes, it returns the error message and yes, the script will stop continuing.